# If $f(x)=\frac{15^x - 3^x - 5^x + 1}{x \tan(x)}$, $x\ne0$ is continous at $x=0$, then find $f(0)$

Tags: continuity

This is a question from maharastra state board's commercial maths paper 2017. I have no idea how to solve this question.

If $f(x)=\frac{15^x - 3^x - 5^x + 1}{x\tan(x)}$, $x\ne0$ is continous at $x=0$, then find $f(0)$

Another query:- if $x\ne0$ then how can it be continous and how does $f(0)$ exist???

Comment: With regard to your "Another query", the problem could have been worded better, but the intended question was this: If f is defined for all x (including x = 0), and if, for nonzero x, the value of f(x) is given by the specified formula, what must be the value of f(0) given that f is continuous at x = 0?

Comment: Well...I think you should evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0-}f(x)$...Double application of L' Hospital's Rule gives answer to be $\ln(3)\ln(5)$

Answer (score 2):

We must have $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=f(0)$ to be countinous, but
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{15^x - 3^x - 5^x + 1}{x \tan(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\frac{5^x-1}{x}\frac{3^x-1}{x}}{\frac{\tan x}{x}}=\ln5.\ln3$$

Answer (score 1):

You have to compute the limit
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{15^x-5^x-3^x+1}{x \tan x}$$
and this will be your $f(0)$. Now, your function can be written as
$$\frac{5^x-1}{x} \cdot \frac{3^x-1}{x} \cdot \frac{x}{\sin x} \cdot \cos x$$
where each factor has finite limit.  Hence your function tends to
$$\log 5 \cdot \log 3 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \log 5 \log 3$$

This means that
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{15^x-5^x-3^x+1}{x \tan x}  &, &x \neq 0 \\
\log 5 \log 3 & , & x=0
\end{cases} $$ is a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{15^x - 3^x - 5^x + 1}{x \tan(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(3^x-1)\cdot (5^x-1)}{x\cdot tan x}\cdot \frac{x}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(3^x-1)\cdot (5^x-1)}{x^2} = ln3\cdot ln5$$